# Probem with XCode and C Program

Tags: c, linux, xcode, graphing

My computer has suddenly stopped opening XCode to display graphs generated by running a previously-tested C program. It's giving me the following error (which it always did before even when it worked), and then just freezes when it immediately used to open the graphs.

```
(base) [~]$ root plot_hard_RE.C
root [0] 
Processing plot_hard_RE.C...
Warning: wrong member access operator '.' plot_hard_RE.C:2:
```

When I do control - c, it doesn't take me back to root. Instead it just says "There was a crash.
This is the entire stack trace of all threads: ..."

Does any have any ideas on how I can troubleshoot this problem?

I am on a Linux machine but SSH'ing into a server.

Note: When someone else SSH into the server and tries the same command from their machine, it works fine. I think it's a problem with my machine.

Comment: is `(base) [~]$ root` the prompt and your command `plot_hard_RE.C` ? in that case the shell try to execute the commands from `plot_hard_RE.C` which is invalid for that of course. Perhaps you wanted to execute `plot_hard_RE` if this the name of your executable, or you missed to start xcode like doing `xcode plot_hard_RE` ?

Comment: No, the prompt is (base) [working directory]$ and the command is root plot_hard_RE.C

Comment: `root` starts Xcode ? what is the command `root` for you ? On which OS are you ?

Comment: Should I be using a different command to run the program? It used to work fine. Not sure why it's suddenly crashing. It's also working fine for my advisor when they SSH into the server and try it on their machine.

Comment: did defined an alias for an other command named `root` ? do `which root` to know where *root* is found for instance. For me to name a command *root* is a weird choice

Comment: Yes it says "alias root='root -l'
 ~/rootvts/bin/root"

Comment: the other people also have that alias ? (note I suppose the alias is "alias root='root -l ~/rootvts/bin/root'") where I moved the second `'` at the end)